Elpaca: problems with eglot version and flymake
I am using elpaca as my package manager. When I try to install flymake, using the use-package compatibility, I am getting the following error:
eldoc installed version (1 13 0) lower than min required 1.14

In fact, elpaca-info informs me that indeed I have version 1.13 of eldoc, but flymake requires 1.14.
So logically, I tried to pull a newer version of eldoc from GNU ELPA, by adding:
(use-package eldoc
  :config
  (provide 'upgraded-eldoc))


But now I have a warning every time I open emacs:
Warning (emacs): eldoc loaded before Elpaca activation

How can I solve this?
Ideally, I would like elpaca to resolve dependencies on its own and not have to explicitly include the use-package eldoc in my config.

Please use Elpaca's github issue tracker for support requests. I (author of Elpaca) don't use Stack Exchange.

Apparently elpaca wants to configure eldoc before eldoc is first loaded, for whatever reason. But your use of use-package has already loaded eldoc, thus the warning. Just do (use-package eldoc :defer t) to avoid immediately loading the eldoc package. This ensures that eldoc’s autoloads are loaded, but the rest of the package is not.
See the use-package Manual for more information.

(use-package eldoc :defer t) is not working for me. It still produces Warning (emacs): eldoc loaded before Elpaca activation.

/me shrugs. You may have some other problem as well. Does it happen if you run emacs -Q? If not, then the problem is somewhere in your init file.
